# using linq with subsonic 3

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic3

How can I do this task define in comments please help me...

```
var qry = DB.Select.From("EventListing").OrderDesc("CreatedOn").Where("StartTime", Comparison.GreaterThan,
SelectedDate.AddDays(-1));
// TODO LIMIT TO TOP (based on Max) RESULTS
// where StartTime is the same date as SelectedDate
//qry.TopSpec = "5";
var events = qry.ExecuteTypedList<EventListing>();
```

Comment: yo man try to describe your problem yo

Comment: I have written in commeents area of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely clear on the problem but if you are just looking for the top X results then use the `Take()` method.  [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).  For your example the usage would be:

```
var qry = DB.Select.From("EventListing").OrderDesc("CreatedOn").Where("StartTime", Comparison.GreaterThan, SelectedDate.AddDays(-1)).Take(5);
```